# PHP variable stores id but I need column name in order to carry out comparison in SQL statement

Tags: php, sql

I have some drop down boxes that store counties and constituencies in them.

When you select an item from the drop down and click a search button, the value that is returned is the primary key id of the selected county or constituency.

```
<option value="<?php htmlout($county['ids']); ?>">
<option value="<?php htmlout($constituency['ids']); ?>">
```

These values are successfully returned as I can output them using:

```
    $countyid = $_GET['county'];
$constituencyid = $_GET['constituency'];

<?php echo $countyid ?>
<?php echo $constituencyid ?>
```

I then have an sql statement as follows:

```
    $sqlparams = array();

if($countyid !== '') {
    $sqlparams[] = "county = '$countyid'";
}
if($constituencyid !== '') {
    $sqlparams[] = "constituency = '$constituencyid'";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pt";

if (count($sqlparams) > 0) {
    $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $sqlparams); 
}
```

This is then executed and the results stored in an array and all of this works.

However, the problem is that for instance with the following example:

```
if($countyid !== '') {
    $sqlparams[] = "county = '$countyid'";
}
```

I am comparing 'county' a VARCHAR column with '$countyid' an integer.

I want to know the best way to get the name of the county in place of that $countyid variable if that makes sense so that I am comparing a VARCHAR with a VARCHAR.

I apologise if this is very simple but I am confused as to how to do this.

I understand that I could change the value of the dropdown to return the name but there is some stuff going on in the background that requires the id to be returned and I am pretty sure that it is good practice to return the id as this is very flexible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a table Counties with columns name and countyid:

`$sqlparams[] = "county IN (SELECT name FROM counties WHERE countyid = $countyid)"`

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback on this.  This works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The west way to do this is using [parameter binding with pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pt 
    WHERE county = :countyid AND constituency = :constituencyid";

$sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$sth->bindParam(':countyid', $countyid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':constituencyid', $constituencyid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Not only can you define what type of value you want to bind (`PDO::PARAM_INT`), this also prevents SQL Injection.

Comment: need to adjust for not all parameters being given... and varchar vs int type mismatch on county

Comment: SQL injection would have been the comment I was just going to make :)